# Configure ScalaQuery in a Play 2.0 project

Tags: playframework-2.0, scalaquery

I wanted to try out using ScalaQuery with the Play! Framework (version 2.0.2) but I can't get it to work. I added the following line to the Build.scala file :

```
  val appDependencies = Seq(
    "org.scalaquery" %% "scalaquery" % "0.9.5"
  )
```

But when I run the 'play dependencies' command i keep getting

```
sbt.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: org.scalaquery#scalaquery_2.9.1;0.9.5: not found
```

I tried to add the jars to the IntelliJ but obviously that wasn't enough, and I have no idea how I would get play to recognize the jars.
Has anyone succeded to get ScalaQuery (or Slick) to work in Play 2 ?

Comment: Have you tried just adding the jar directly to the `lib/` directory in your project?  Play picks up dependencies from there automatically.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the current [ScalaQuery download page](http://scalaquery.org/download.html), it has been built against scala-2.9.0-1 whereas Play is using scala-2.9.1. So you need to explicitly append the scala version you want of your dependency:

```
"org.scalaquery" % "scalaquery_2.9.0-1" % "0.9.5"
```